# Gdata Export Document----Conflict Error

Tags: python, gdata

So this is rather worrying--I hope that someone can give me a hand with this one.

I am using a python script to download google doc spreadsheets and then back them up to our servers. MOST of the time, it works well, but every so often I get an error that looks like this:

```
gdata.service.RequestError: {'status': 409, 'body': '', 'reason': 'Conflict'}
```

Here is all of the code that I am using. Does somebody know if  the Export function has some strange behavior that could be causing this?

```
QC_GoogleDoc_Spreadsheet_AutoLog
Author: Christopher James Johnson
Date: May 22, 2012

try:
  from xml.etree import ElementTree
except ImportError:
  from elementtree import ElementTree
import gdata.spreadsheet.service
import gdata.service
import atom.service
import gdata.spreadsheet
import gdata.docs.service
import atom
import getopt
import sys
import string
import time
import shutil
import os
import getpass
import tempfile
import csv
import time
import datetime
import glob


def main():

    archiver = backUpper()


class backUpper():

  def __init__(self):





gd = gdata.docs.service.DocsService()    


self.gd_client = gdata.docs.service.DocsService()  
self.gd_client.email = 'xxxx.xxxx'
self.gd_client.password = 'xxxxxxxx'
self.gd_client.source = 'Spreadsheets GData Sample'
self.gd_client.ProgrammaticLogin()
self.curr_key = ''
self.curr_wksht_id = ''
self.list_feed = None
self.autoLogPath = ""


spreadsheets_client = gdata.spreadsheet.service.SpreadsheetsService()
spreadsheets_client.email = self.gd_client.email
spreadsheets_client.password = self.gd_client.password
spreadsheets_client.source = "My Fancy Spreadsheet Downloader"
spreadsheets_client.ProgrammaticLogin()

feed = spreadsheets_client.GetSpreadsheetsFeed()

for i, entry in enumerate(feed.entry):
  if isinstance(feed, gdata.spreadsheet.SpreadsheetsSpreadsheetsFeed):
    if isinstance(entry, gdata.spreadsheet.SpreadsheetsSpreadsheet):
      print entry.title.text
      x = entry.id.text
      print x
      self.Download(entry)


self.DeleteTemporaryFiles()


def Download(self, entry):
line = entry.id.text
title = entry.title.text
splitLine = line.split('/')
key = splitLine[-1]

backUpDir = R'\\cob-hds-1\compression\QC\QCing\otherFiles\GoogleDocBackUp' + '\\'

now = datetime.datetime.now()
hour = now.hour
today = datetime.date.today()
if not os.path.exists(backUpDir + str(today)):
  os.mkdir(backUpDir + str(today))
if not os.path.exists(backUpDir + str(today) + '\\' + str(hour)):
  os.mkdir(backUpDir + str(today) + '\\' + str(hour))

backupDir = backUpDir + str(today) + '\\' + str(hour)

tempfile.tempdir = backupDir
file_path = tempfile.mkstemp(suffix='.xls')    

uri = 'http://docs.google.com/feeds/documents/private/full/%s' % key

spreadsheets_client = gdata.spreadsheet.service.SpreadsheetsService()
spreadsheets_client.email = self.gd_client.email
spreadsheets_client.password = self.gd_client.password
spreadsheets_client.source = "My Fancy Spreadsheet Downloader"
spreadsheets_client.ProgrammaticLogin()

# ...
docEntry = self.gd_client.GetDocumentListEntry(uri)

docs_auth_token = self.gd_client.GetClientLoginToken()
self.gd_client.SetClientLoginToken(spreadsheets_client.GetClientLoginToken())
self.gd_client.Export(docEntry, file_path[1])
shutil.copy(file_path[1], backupDir + '//' + title + '.xls')


os.close(file_path[0])
self.gd_client.SetClientLoginToken(docs_auth_token)     


if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

So the scary part--This just started happening THIS MORNING! Everything was great before...and this morning...something has started happening with this and other Gdata using python scripts! Please help!

Thanks!

EDIT: So a co-worker of mine was working on one of these spreadsheets at the time and both of our programs crashed. (Mine backs up the google docs and his writes to it. If we are both working on the same spreadsheet at the same time, could this create a problem?)

Comment: Does gdata have no ability to check for others writing to file/"locking" the file in order to have exclusive access?

Comment: Not that I know of, but it would not surprise me at all.

Comment: I've seen a huge uptick with this error in my doc now. It used to be very infrequent. The doc is not shared so I don't know of a true edit conflict that would cause this in my case.